# Azure Devops pipeline , way to know when pipeline is done , using self hosted agent

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline which I invoke it using azure rest API

```
https://dev.azure.com/xxx/xxx_connection/_apis/pipelines/2/runs
```

All working great, I'm sending the source files from install Self Hosted Linux Agent to azure and getting them back compiled into the Self Hosted Linux Agent.

My question is how can I know when the pipeline is done in the server that is hosting the Self Hosted Linux Agent?

Is there any callback? or API I can invoke and query the if the pipeline job is done?
or just doing while loop on the directory where I accepting to get the compiled products?
last option I want to avoid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also check out below ways to know if the pipeline is done.

1, Using [Runs-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) or [Latest - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) API to get the build result as mentioned by Shayki Abramczyk.

2, You can set up a [service hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/overview?view=azure-devops). For below example a [web hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops) which is triggered on the the completion the selected build pipeline.

[image]

3, You can check out the extension [CatLight](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=catlight.catlight). CatLight app will notify you on build start and completion.

4,Create a custom notification on the build completed event and subscribe. You will be notified by email when the pipeline completed. Check the [tutorial here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/notifications/manage-team-group-notifications?view=azure-devops) for more information.

Comment: Thanks @Levi Lu-MSFT
Can you please check this question :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044989/azure-pipeline-how-to-use-bigger-server-for-hosted-agent-builds

Comment: Hi @user63898 You cannot increase the ram and CPUs for hosted agent. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#what-if-i-need-a-bigger-machine-with-more-processing-power-memory-or-disk-space). If you donot want to create self-hosted agent. You can check out [parallel jobs](https://medium.com/@mehmetugurgural/reducing-longer-build-times-in-ci-pipelines-parallel-builds-build-agents-with-azure-devops-8aa5c22987f8)

Comment: how can i do parallel jobs ? as the work flow is sequential?
I'm downloading the ruby-> fastlan->cocopods-> compile
how can i divide it to jobs ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Runs - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) API:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

And in the response check the `result` (should be `succeeded`).

You can get the `runId` when you invoke the pipeline with the API you mentioned (in the response).

Answer (score 0):

You can poll the pipeline every 30 seconds to find out the status of your build, script will exit once status is succeeded.

```
$user="$(USER)"
$token="$(TOKEN)"
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))
$buildInfo = ( Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri "https://tfs.com/tfs/Organization/Project/_apis/build/builds/${buildID}?api-version=6.1-preview.6" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} )
Write-Host "Build URL : " "https://tfs.com/tfs/Organization/Project/_build/results?buildId=$buildID"
      while($buildInfo.status -eq "inProgress" -or $buildInfo.status -eq "notStarted") # keep checking till build completed
      {
       Write-Output "Build is $($buildInfo.status) Sleep for 30 seconds."
       Start-Sleep -Seconds 30 # Start sleep for 30 seconds
       $buildInfo = ( Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -UseDefaultCredentials -Uri "https://tfs.com/tfs/Organization/Project/_apis/build/builds/${buildID}?api-version=6.1-preview.6" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} )
      }

      Write-Output "Build Status : $($buildInfo.status)" # print build status
      Write-Output "Build Result : $($buildInfo.result)" # print build result
```