# Azure pipeline How to use bigger server for hosted agent builds?

Tags: macos, azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-pipelines

I don't understand but how do I set in the hosted azure pipeline build server to be a bigger machine with more ram and more CPU's?
i want to avoid installing a self-hosted agent on one of the Azure VM's I just want to use more stronger hosted agent, where can i configure this?
I'm using a hosted MAC agent.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Please check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#capabilities-and-limitations)

> If Microsoft-hosted agents don't meet your needs, then you can deploy your own self-hosted agents or use scale set agents.

Comment: i did read the documentation, and i saw this, this is strange to me why i need to install from scratch on azure VM self-hosted agent. 
i just want to make my hosted agent bigger .. i don't want to manage agent .. ,

Comment: There is no option for MAC agents. For Linux of Windows you can try use scale sets
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/scale-set-agents?view=azure-devops Sorry for having bad message, but really you are on your own and your self hosted agents here.

Comment: This is possible on Github Actions but not Azure DevOps.